# Expression has changed after it was checked.

Tags: angular

On teh second time setting visibility of textarea component it throws the error mentioned in the title. 
Here is a plunker to demonstrate the problem: https://plnkr.co/edit/jW4KXfsI7WLgQxI1ne0r?p=preview
The problematic component's code:

```
import {Component, OnInit, ElementRef, ViewChild, Input, forwardRef, ChangeDetectorRef} from "@angular/core";
import {ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR} from "@angular/forms";

const noop = () => {
};

export const CUSTOM_INPUT_CONTROL_VALUE_ACCESSOR: any = {
  provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
  useExisting: forwardRef(() => TextareaComponent),
  multi: true
};

@Component({
  selector: 'app-textarea',
  templateUrl: './textarea.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./textarea.component.scss'],
  providers: [CUSTOM_INPUT_CONTROL_VALUE_ACCESSOR]
})
export class TextareaComponent implements OnInit, ControlValueAccessor  {

  private _value = '';
  private _defaultLimit: number = 200;
  @Input('charLimit')
  private _charLimit: number;
  @Input('lineLimit')
  private _lineLimit:number;
  @Input('doLimitChar')
  private _doLimitChar: boolean = true;
  @ViewChild('storyText')
  private _textAreaElement: ElementRef;
  private _disabled: boolean = false;
  /** Callback registered via registerOnTouched (ControlValueAccessor) */
  private _onTouchedCallback: () => void = noop;
  /** Callback registered via registerOnChange (ControlValueAccessor) */
  private _onChangeCallback: (_: any) => void = noop;

  constructor(private _crf:ChangeDetectorRef) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._charLimit = this._charLimit || this._defaultLimit;
  }

  get value():any {
    return this._value;
  }

  set value(v: any) {
    if (!v) v = "";
    if (this._doLimitChar) {
      v = v.substring(0, this._charLimit);
    }
    this._value = v;
    this._textAreaElement.nativeElement.value = v;
    this._onChangeCallback(v);
  }

  // get empty() {
  //   return ( this.value == null || this.value === '')
  // }
  //
  // get charCount(): number {
  //   return this.empty ? 0 : ('' + this.value).length;
  // }

  get remainingCharacterCount(): number {
    return this._charLimit - this.value.length;
  }

  get linesNumber():number {
    return this.value.split('\n').length;
  }

  /** Implemented as part of ControlValueAccessor. */
  writeValue(value: any) {
    this.value = value;
  }

  /** Implemented as part of ControlValueAccessor. */
  registerOnChange(fn: any) {
    this._onChangeCallback = fn;
  }

  /** Implemented as part of ControlValueAccessor. */
  registerOnTouched(fn: any) {
    this._onTouchedCallback = fn;
  }

  /** Implemented as a part of ControlValueAccessor. */
  setDisabledState(isDisabled: boolean) {
    this._disabled = isDisabled;
  }

}
```

Comment: The problem is in `Story.tldr` property. You can set initial value to `''` for this https://plnkr.co/edit/FUTWfhlbTDjIIrQPqpAx?p=preview

Comment: So it won't change between undefined and ' ', ahaa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what exactly causes the error but `detectChanges()` fixes it

```
  toggleTldr() {
    this.isTldrVisible = !this.isTldrVisible;
    this.crf.detectChanges();
  }
```

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/c7g77NHmECjgrkDx6TaM?p=preview)

The difference to `markForCheck()` is, that `detectChanges()` runs change detection immediately.

I guess the root cause is that you mix template-driven (`ngModel`) and reactive forms (`FormBuilder`).